# How to check the system rights of a user in C++

Tags: c++, windows, system, privileges

I've only been able to find an answer to the need for AdministatorRights here, and so I ask for help on this one.  I hope I didn't miss an answer elsewhere, I truly apologize if I did.

Anyhow, I'm trying to write a simple program to search for the [rights of the user](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd349804%28v=WS.10%29.aspx).

I planned to iterate through the list and return the rights of the user, but I hit a road bump in that there is [no method, as far as I see, to check if a user has the given privilege](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721849%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  I've been able to find information on attempting to change the status of the user rights, but not a simple call to see if they are enabled or disabled.  Does anyone know a way around this method?  I'm a bit stuck in how to achieve this, any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to distinguish between privileges and rights. In the Windows security model, they're *not* the same things.

Comment: Oops, did not know this.  Well in that case the rights!

Comment: @JerryCoffin: privileges are sometimes referred to as rights, even by Microsoft.  The document the OP links to is one example.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Yes, MS screws up sometimes, but that doesn't really make the question any more understandable.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: I'm afraid I'm not sure what distinction you're trying to draw here.  Do you call `SeInteractiveLogonRight` and `SeBackupPrivilege` privileges or rights?  If they're privileges, what is an example of a right?  If they're rights, what is an example of a privilege?

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Backup privilege is a privilege, interactive logon is a right. Rights are granted (or not) to an account. Privileges often go with a right, but must also be enabled before they can be used. For example, to adjust the system clock, the account must have the right to do so, *and* the program doing the adjusting must enable the SE_SYSTEMTIME_NAME privilege with [AdjustTokenPrivileges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375202.aspx).

Comment: If the account doesn't have the required rights, then `AdjustTokenPrivileges` will fail--but even if the account has the proper *rights*, attempting to use that right will fail unless the privilege has been enabled (assuming the action is one that requires a privilege, obviously).

Comment: @JerryCoffin: from the programmer's (and the kernels) point of view, there is no difference between `SeInteractiveLogonRight` and `SeBackupPrivilege`.  One is named a right and the other a privilege, but you manipulate them in exactly the same way.

Comment: From your description it sounds as if you want to describe them as privileges when they are in an access token, but rights when they are associated with a user account?  That is, would you say "the user's rights determine which privileges are added to the access token for a process"?

Comment: From the programmer's point of view, the two are completely different. Specifically, an account generally can't assign itself any rights. Either it already has the rights, or else those rights are completely unavailable. A process most certainly *can* enable privileges (and if it wishes to carry out certain actions, it *must* do so).

Comment: @JerryCoffin: OK, although rights and privileges are mostly handled identically, I've done some testing and there is indeed at least one functional difference.  Specifically, rights are not included in access tokens - which is admittedly extremely relevant to this particular question, and something I was not aware of.  To be fair, it's irrelevant in most other scenarios.  (For example, you assign a right to an account or group in the exact same way you would assign a privilege.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Yes, I wasn't bringing it up just to be anal--given the question, it really did seem like a relevant distinction.

Comment: @user3072634: To check rights (not privileges) you might want to check [Microsoft's example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446637.aspx), though it's a little long to post here (250+ lines of code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [`GetTokenInformation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446671%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the `TokenPrivileges` option.

You can use [`OpenProcessToken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379295%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`OpenThreadToken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379296%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get a handle to the access token you want to query.

Comment: Note that as per the discussion above, this will only work for true privileges (with names like `SeBackupPrivilege`) and not for rights (with names like `SeInteractiveLogonRight`) because the latter are not included in the access token.  To determine which rights an account has is significantly more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`LsaEnumerateAccountRights`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms721790%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but it only seems to report what rights are assigned specifically to that account and does not include the rights that are conveyed via group membership.